# recordset filter by length of a string colum

Tags: vb.net, filter, recordset

This is in VB.NET.

I have a requirement to display only the values of a column where the length of the column value is greater than 1.

I used the below approach.

objRecordSet.Filter = "LEN(FIRSTNAME) > 1"

But it is not working. 
Can you please suggest me if there is any issue in the above code or if there is any other alternative.

Thanks 
Vaas

Comment: Please add a tag indicating which language you are writing in.

Comment: I have added the VB.NET tag.

Comment: How is it not working? If displaying names that look like they are length = 1 are you sure that is the case?

Comment: Yes the above is not working. I have to display the names which have length more than 1.